# How to reduce re-render when updating state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `MarketList` component that fetches market id's and a `MarketCard` component that fetches info for a given market based on the id. Because I want the markets to be filterable by info, I'm saving the market info in the `MarketList` component. However, this causes what appears to be n^2 re-renders.

MarketList

```
type Market = {
  id: string;
};

type MarketInfo = {
  [key: string]: { title: 'title'; description: 'description' };
};

const MarketList = () => {
  const [markets, setMarkets] = useState<Market[]>([]);
  const [marketsInfo, setMarketsInfo] = useState<MarketInfo>({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchedMarkets = getMarkets();
    setMarkets(fetchedMarkets);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {markets.map((market) => (
        <MarketCard
          key={market.id}
          market={market}
          marketInfo={marketsInfo[market.id]}
          updateMarketInfo={(info) =>
            setMarketsInfo((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [market.id]: info }))
          }
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

MarketCard

```
const MarketCard = (market, marketInfo, updateMarketInfo) => {
  console.log('MARKET CARD');
  useEffect(() => {
    if (marketInfo) {
      return;
    }
    const fetchedMarketInfo = getMarketInfo(market.id);
    updateMarketInfo(fetchedMarketInfo);
  }, [marketInfo]);
  return <div>{marketInfo.title}</div>;
};
```

The async network requests themselves are near instant. I would like a Card component not to be re-rendered if the `marketInfo` for a given Card exists.

screen grab of console:

[image]

Comment: `const MarketCard = (market, marketInfo, updateMarketInfo)` should be `const MarketCard = ({market, marketInfo, updateMarketInfo})`

Comment: Also, every time `marketInfo` updates, you update the `marketInfo` again, why?

Comment: `marketInfo={marketsInfo[market.id]}` it causes unnecesary renders. Also I would call `getMarketInfo` in the parent component, not in MarketCard. Because your current implementation creates 2 way dependency. This will cause unnecesary rerenders.

Comment: sounds like you need memo: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/memo

Comment: @SedatPolat I'd like the MarketCards/marketInfo to load independently of each other since I'm using ipfs for storage and on occasion 1 request will timeout and hang up everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use React.memo (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) and pass a function to the second argument to react memo to only change if the specific info for the MarketCard component is changed.

Comment: [link to the better written beta react docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/memo)

Comment: This helped a considerable amount. I didn't realize memo accepted a second arg.
`export default memo(
  MarketCard,
  (oldProps, newProps) => oldProps.marketInfo === newProps.marketInfo,
);`